# Angular5 add jwt token

Tags: javascript, angular

I have made the interceptor class that looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }
    //
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
              next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const idToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
        console.log('daniel3');
        if (idToken) {
            let cloned = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`
                }
            });
            console.log('daniel4');
            return next.handle(cloned);
        }
        else {
            console.log('daniel5');
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

but this strangely works only one-time meaning adding jwt token to request, there is no some hidden magic so any leads are much welcome.

Comment: There should only be  one import of the HttpClientModule for the app. Each import will create a new copy of HttpClient  and the interceptor provided in a root module could be overwritten.

Comment: Yes i had 2 imports, removed one and all working well now

Comment: Sure.i have written it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should only be one import of the HttpClientModule for the app. Each import will create a new copy of HttpClient and the interceptor provided in a root module could be overwritten